# Python, разделение строки по символам через метод re.split

Tags: python, python-3.x, строки, split

**Необходимо разделить входящую строку по числам и буквам**, например:

```
s = "k10Z18i13Q19u"
a = re.split("(\d*)", s)
```

На выходе получим:

```
['k', '10', 'Z', '18', 'i', '13', 'Q', '19', 'u']
```

Но так же получим ошибку:

```
FutureWarning: split() requires a non-empty pattern match.
  return _compile(pattern, flags).split(string, maxsplit)
```

Данный метод очень подходит для решения моей задачи, но не пойму, отчего ошибки. Именно шаблон для разделения строки `(\d*)` взял из чужого решения, но не знаю как именно он работает, не смог найти описания.
**Можете подсказать, что делаю не так или каким методом лучше решить данную задачу?**

Comment: *"не смог найти описания"* — практически любое руководство по регулярным выражениям, использующим PCRE синтаксис (самая популярная разновидность),  будет содержать описание `\d*` (распознаёт ноль или более цифр). Регулярные выражения являются полезным инструментом.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Замените `(\d*)` на `(\d+)`

Поясню что не так: `(\d*)` подразумевает ноль или более цифр. То есть пустым разделитель тоже может быть. Если это учитывать, то ваш результат мог быть и таким:

```
['', 'k', '10', 'Z', '18', 'i', '13', 'Q', '19', 'u', '']
```

Также если бы у вас были две буквы подряд, то между ними тоже могла бы "найтись" пустая строка. Текущая реализация этого метода не находит пустые подстроки, которые могут подходить под регулярное выражение. Однако в будущем планируется это реализовать, поэтому вы получаете *FutureWarning*. Вас предупреждают, что если вы ничего не измените, после обновления вас может ожидать сюрприз.

См. также [re.split](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.split)